# How to update the badge number in IOS notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, notifications, push-notification

I recently use the Amazon SNS to push notification for my IOS app.

It works well, the only problem I have encountered is when I receive the notification , the badge number will not be updated, here is how I implement:

First I follow the example here
https://aws.amazon.com/articles/9156883257507082
, I extract only the SNS part that means I only alter the appdelegate in my app. Here is the example code from the tutorial.

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", userInfo];
    NSLog(@"%@",msg);
    [[Constants universalAlertsWithTitle:@"Push Notification Received" andMessage:msg] show];
}


-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Register for push notification
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    if(launchOptions!=nil){
        NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", launchOptions];
        NSLog(@"%@",msg);
        [[Constants universalAlertsWithTitle:@"Push Notification Received" andMessage:msg] show];
    }

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    Message_BoardViewController *boardViewController = [Message_BoardViewController new];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [UINavigationController new];

    navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

    [navigationController pushViewController:boardViewController animated:NO];
    [boardViewController release];

    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [navigationController release];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Logging Control - Do NOT use logging for non-development builds.
#ifdef DEBUG
    [AmazonLogger verboseLogging];
#else
    [AmazonLogger turnLoggingOff];
#endif

    [AmazonErrorHandler shouldNotThrowExceptions];

    return YES;
}
```

As you can see, the badge number will always become 0, and also I found the JSON incoming notification from SNS is without badge field but only has alert field, didReceiveRemoteNotification is not call when the app is at background too. 
So , how can I modify the code to update the badge? Thanks for kindly help.

Comment: ?? are you that set every time `application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;`

Comment: Are you setting the badge number in the notification body?

Comment: do you mean the notificaiton json should include the badge number?